# Custom Intellij template setter to do simple fieldname subString

Tags: java, intellij-idea, getter-setter

I am trying to write a custom setter using intellij template's which needs to do simple subString on fieldName if it starts with specific prefix, for example "i_"

I have a class as follows:

```
public class Summary {
    public long i_duration;
}
```

Using the default Setter generation in intellij outputs:

```
public class Summary {
    public long i_duration;

    public long getI_duration() {
        return i_duration;
    }
}
```

Am trying to achieve

```
public class Summary {
    public long i_duration;

    public long getDuration() {
        return i_duration;
    }
}
```

What I have tried so far is copying Intelij's Template and using combination of StringUtil.startsWith() and StringUtil.substringAfter() to strip the "i_" from field name before using as part of method name. However I'm leaking a space somewhere and getting an error while I'm using the template below.

> Incorrect method 'long get Duration() { return i_duration; }'

As we can see there appears to be a space inserted between 'get' and 'Duration'. Below is my custom template for Setter Generation

```
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
$field.type ##
#set($fieldName = $field.name)
#set($rejectPrefix = "i_")
#if ($StringUtil.startsWith(${fieldName}, ${rejectPrefix}))
    #set($fieldName = $StringUtil.substringAfter(${fieldName}, ${rejectPrefix}))
#end    
#if($field.recordComponent)
    ${fieldName}##
#else
    #set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier(${fieldName})))
    #if ($field.boolean && $field.primitive)
    is##
    #else
    get##
    #end
    ${name}##
#end
() {
return $field.name;
}
```

Default Intelij Default Template for Setter Generation

```
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
$field.type ##
#if($field.recordComponent)
  ${field.name}##
#else
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))
#if ($field.boolean && $field.primitive)
  is##
#else
  get##
#end
${name}##
#end
() {
  return $field.name;
}
```

There's not lot of documentation around writing custom getter template on intellij but have seen this [Generate custom code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-code.html#customize-templates)

Also seen:
Source code for intellij's [StringUtil](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/util/src/com/intellij/openapi/util/text/StringUtil.java) and [FieldElement](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/0e2aa4030ee763c9b0c828f0b5119f4cdcc66f35/plugins/generate-tostring/src/org/jetbrains/java/generate/element/FieldElement.java) class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working, sharing for everyone below. Still don't understand why did it work this way, someone from intellij community could explain us better

```
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
$field.type ##
#set($fieldName = $field.name)
#set($rejectPrefix = "m_")
#if ($StringUtil.startsWith(${fieldName}, ${rejectPrefix}))
    #set($fieldName = $StringUtil.substringAfter(${fieldName}, ${rejectPrefix}))
#end    
#if($field.recordComponent)
    ${fieldName}##
#else
    #set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier(${fieldName})))
    #if ($field.boolean && $field.primitive)
    is${name}##
    #else
    get${name}##
    #end
#end
() {
return $field.name;
}
```

I assumed each usage of ## could be leaking space or auto-inserting them, so merged if-else block on is## and get## with single ${name}## in end to
if-else block on is${name}## and get${name}##